# Closure scenario: Why function passed parameter is assigned in closure scope

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand how closure works. Please take a look at below code

```
if (true) {
    let a = 40;

    function add(b) {
        return () => {
            let c = a + b;
            console.log(c);
        }
    }

    console.dir(add(10));
}
```

> Case1: a variable is in block scope
>
> Case2: b variable is in closure scope why? Not understanding

**Output:**

[image]

Please put some light on Case2? why is it so?

Comment: Function returned by the `add` function has a closure over the local scope of `add` function and the local scope of function `a` includes the parameter `b` as well. Function `add` has a closure over the `if` block which includes variable `a`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266831/till-what-level-do-closures-keep-their-execution-contexts. In short, closure is just a reference to the environment in which a function is created. Reference to the environment is saved in the internal `[[Environment]]` slot on the function object.

Comment: They're both closures. Stop thinking that closure is a type of scope. It's not. A closure is an instance of scope. For example in your code above `40` is a number and `a` is 40. You would not consider `a` to be a kind of 40. Instead `a` is an instance of a number that stores the value 40. Similarly a closure is an instance of a scope. Closures stores scopes.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is in block scope for the `anonymous function` returned by calling `add`
*and*
`b` is in the closure scope for the `anonymous function` returned by calling `add`

so a function is going to keep any variables needed in the closure scope even when the outer function has exited and all its local variables are garbage collected except b which is needed for the anonymous function . hence it lives in the closure scope of it

hence you may add more to closure scope like so;

```
if (true) {
    let a = 40;

    function add(b) {
        let d = 55;
        return () => {
            let c = a + b +d;
            console.log(c);
        }
    }

    console.dir(add(10));
}
```

now in the closure scope we have `b` and `d` ( they both are local variables to function add and are needed by the inner function)

similarly if the variable `d` was not required, then it won't be in its closure scope like so

```
if (true) {
let a = 40;

function add(b) {
    let d = 55;
    return () => {
        let c = a + b;
        console.log(c);
    }
}

console.dir(add(10));
```

}

now in the closure scope we only have `b`.

so its not the function passed in parameter that is assigned in closure scope. it can be any local variable which is needed. for eg:

```
if (true) {
    let a = 40;

    function add(b) {
        let d = 55;
        return () => {
            let c = a + d;
            console.log(c);
        }
    }

    console.dir(add(10));
}
```

now we dont have `b` in closure even it is a passed parameter. its just `d` in closure scope.